# Struts2: value from Action - DAO (database) - VO - View (jsp). Suggest?

Tags: java, struts2

In my struts 2 application, I am generating a textual report in jsp. I have already fetched all the required value from databases in ResultSet available in my DAO class. Now, please suggest the best way to get all the values (present in ResultSet) in my jsp page to show the report. I don’t want to write any login in my jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VO, a simple POJO, seems a good choice. Can be done with a list of map, too. It depends which is suitable there.